# making incoming phonecall to android runnung in emulator

Tags: android, debugging, call

I'm trying to develop small app that will be registered on [PhoneStateListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html) and do some magic over incoming voice calls. For debugging purposes I need to trigger onCallStateChanged(...) event from outside of phone, not perform real incoming voicecall.

Is it possible to do this somehow with sending phone number to debugged app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go try these guy over here http://www.anddev.org/video-tut_-_simulating_incoming_phone_calls_-_sms_via_cmd-t135.html

Hope it helps :D